# error al usar variables de funciones en otras funciones en python

Tags: python, funciones, programación-funcional

recién estoy aprendiendo programación funcional en python y como ejercicio tengo hacer un programa que permita guardar un texto introducido por el usuario como fichero .txt pero cada una de las partes de este programa tiene que ser una función por lo que hice lo siguiente:

```
def texto():
    escribir = input("Escriba un texto")
    return escribir

def guardar():
    b = input("Escriba el nombre con el que quiere guardar el archivo")
    wardiola = open(b+".txt", "w")
    wardiola.write(escribir)
    return wardiola

def main():
    texto()
    guardar()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

pero de entrada en escribir se me subraya en rojo indicando que hay un error y cuando lo corro, efectivamente hay un error el cual es el siguiente:

wardiola.write(escribir)
NameError: name 'escribir' is not defined

según yo con el return + nombredevariable ya puedo usar esa variable en otra función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`escribir` solo existe dentro de la función `texto`

Cuando esta función se termina de ejecutar

```
def texto():
    escribir = input("Escriba un texto")
    return escribir
```

La variable no existe más.

Para persistir puedes guardarla como variable y pasarla como argumento.

```
def texto():
    escribir = input("Escriba un texto")
    return escribir

def guardar(escribir):
    b = input("Escriba el nombre con el que quiere guardar el archivo")
    wardiola = open(b+".txt", "w")
    wardiola.write(escribir)
    return wardiola

def main():
    escribir = texto()
    guardar(escribir)
```

De esta forma aunque la variable original `escribir` desaparezca. La estás guardando en una variable y pasándola como argumento, por lo que ya existiría dentro de la función `guardar`